# Razor Page Routing with Friendly Routes not responding

Tags: razor, routes, razor-pages

Following https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing and "Friendly Routes"

With this folder structure:

```
~Pages / (or "Areas" in last example)
External
      PageA
          Index.cshtml
Internal
      PageB
          Index.cshtml
```

And then I want to add these routes

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Even though above guide states this route it...
    // throws exception for "External/PageA" so I have to set "/External/PageA"
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("External/PageA", "/A"); 
    // throws exception for "External/PageB" so I have to set "/External/PageB" 
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("Internal/PageB", "/B");
});
```

But all I'm getting is 404 not found. I've tried multilple combinations. I've even followed the Area setup and moved it to areas with the same structure inside the Area folder:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.AllowAreas = true;
    // Also tried "PageA" and "/PageA", "A" and "/A"
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("External", "/PageA", "/A");
    // Also tried "PageB" and "/PageB", "B" and "/B"
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Internal", "/PageB", "/B");
});
```

It's more like the whole convention setup is totally ignored since there has been 0% progress.

The only way that I can access the page is by writing the full folder name. But I don't want this. I want a cleaner routing structure than the folder structure which at the moment seems impossible.

Any suggestions - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked to:

> The [AddPageRoute] method takes two parameters. The first is the relative path to the Razor page file without the extension

You are providing the path to the *folder* containing the page. You need to add "/Index" to the end of the first argument:

`options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/External/PageA/Index", "A");`

The same is true when working with areas. You need to provide the relative path to the actual page, not the folder name:

`options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("External", "/PageA/Index", "/A");`

This assumes a structure as follows:

`Areas
  External
    Pages
      PageA
        Index.cshtml`